# How can I create an inline link to another user in a Stack Exchange comment thread?

Tags: support, comments

In comments, I frequently see people doing an inline, twitter'ific `@other_user_name` reference that *actually* turns into a link to another user's profile page.

How is this done?

NOTE: This is very likely a duplicate question, but the Googles didn't see fit to find an answer, so perhaps this question should be preserved for people searching for this concept with these words.

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
[@Ross Rogers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/138799) #helpwithlinks
```

Comment: Rendered like: [@Ross Rogers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/138799) #helpwithlinks

Comment: However, according to [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019), this won't give a notification. (I'm not 100% sure if this is still true.)

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend that you do not do this.

There is already a link to the addressed user in the comments, since comment replies by definition can only refer to previous commenters (and always the post owner too).

Comment: After reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work it is now clear to me that you can properly reference another user _and_ _receive_ _no_ _inline_ _visual_ _feedback_ that my inline reference/user notification request actually worked.  I came upon an old question on which I wanted to spur clarification though comments, but I didn't think I was referring to other people correctly.

Comment: Now I believe I actually  _was_ using references to other users correctly, but I thought they were failing because my `@foo` wasn't turning into links, whereas I saw other people's name references turn into links when they created links outside of this canonical user reference flow.

Comment: the correct references to this are the "help" link under the [add comment] button, and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting